# TypeError: OneTalk() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python

```
import host
Noms = "Name"

def init():
    host.registerHandler('ChatReceivedExtended', onTalk) # extended to distinguish between local chat and whispers

def deinit():
    host.unregisterHandler('ChatReceivedExtended', onTalk)

def onTalk(bnet, user, message, isWhisper, payload):
    if isWhisper and user.getName() == Noms:
        bnet.queueChatCommand("/me " + message)
        bnet.queueChatCommand("/f m " + message)
```

When I try to run the script it gives me `"TypeError: OneTalk() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)"`. But when I add username to line 11 it gives me `"TypeError: OneTalk() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)'`.

```
def onTalk(bnet, user, message, isWhisper, payload):

def onTalk(bnet, user, message, isWhisper, payload, username):
```

Comment: Are you sure it says `TypeError: OneTalk()...` and not `TypeError: onTalk()...`?

Comment: It would help if you include the full traceback, and specify what module `host` is.

Answer (score 1):

Based solely on [online](http://pychop.googlecode.com/svn-history/r51/trunk/plugins/python/afk.py) [examples](http://code.google.com/p/pychop/source/browse/trunk/plugins/python/chanstats.py?spec=svn51&r=51), it looks like a method with 4 arguments is expected as the handler, not 5 or 6 as you've attempted.

Try:

```
def onTalk(bnet, user, message, isWhisper):
    if isWhisper and user.getName() == Noms:
        bnet.queueChatCommand("/me " + message)
        bnet.queueChatCommand("/f m " + message)
```

p.s. it would have helped if you included the full traceback, and gave some context to your execution environment (e.g. *"I'm writing a plugin for  [pychop](http://code.google.com/p/pychop/) and ...."*)

Answer (score 0):

Change `onTalk` as in following suggestion, and you'll see, how is actually called:

```
def onTalk( *args, **kwargs):
    print args
    print kwargs
```

Than you can tune the number of parameters.